# Xaml - How to bind with classes & renderers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

I'm having a small issue modding the code below. It works fine except that I have to set the typeface permanently in the `nIcon` class. I want to use it for different typefaces from my xaml file.

In the example code below, I want the typeface to change from the default "FontAwesome" to the "Ionicons" as stated in the xaml file.

Since Xaml does not accept parameters when creating the class, I have no idea how to set it.

Any ideas?

Xaml Code:

```
<controls:nIcon 
    Text="\nf011"
    FontFamily="Ionicons"/>
```

Shared code:

```
public class nIcon : Label
{
    public const string Typeface = "FontAwesome";

    public nIcon()
    {
       \\ FontFamily = Typeface;
    }
}
```

Android Renderer:

```
public class IcDroidRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            Control.Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, nIcon.Typeface + ".ttf");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just use the FontFamily property in XAML?

Comment: @Jason - i need to use a typeface to use that font file in Android e.g "FontAwesome.ttf"

Comment: then just create a typeface property and set it in Xaml